# tunnel to a wss websocket connection with an Authorization header

Tags: node.js, header, tunnel

I am using nodejs and trying to tunnel from localhost:5001 to a remote server using wss://.... using a websocket connection. I want to pass an Authorization header to the wss:// call. I googled and found a wstunnel nodejs library(https://github.com/mhzed/wstunnel) but can't figure out how to pass an Authorization header to the wss://.. remote URL ?

TIA,